I am going for a Christmas holiday at my sister's and brother in-laws house
I am a Zambian female aged 22 who's a medical student at Levy mwanawasa medical university, my sister and brother in-law are both Finnish citizens and intended to visit them this Christmas because my school got a longer break. They are also my. Sole sponsors both school and this trip , however my visa got denied on grounds that I'm financially unstable and haven't made any significant travel

You should add your question to make it clear. Is it "do I need a visa"/"what visa do I need" ?

There is no question in your posting. But I think I understand what you mean. You are worried about the possibility of a visa rejection.
You are not asking for a student visa, you are a student asking for a tourist visa.
Finland does want visitors who come to visit, look at the landscape and culture, spend money, and then leave. Finland does not want immigrants who pretend to be a tourist, enter the country, and then apply for asylum. So you need to make sure that your application looks like a tourist visit.

You need to clarify where they money for the trip comes from, and that it is a gift to you and not a loan which has to be repaid. Sisters helping each other is normal, as long as your sister can afford it.
The visa officials will look at the cost of your trip in comparison to your wealth. Make clear what your sister will provide to you so that you need to spend less money. Your sister should confirm this.
You still need to show stable financial circumstances in Zambia. This includes the money you get from your sister for your studies. You will need account statements showing this, and any other income, and regular expenses, and that should be stable. If suddenly more money arrives for the trip, you have to explain why it came.
You need to show ties to your homeland and a reason to return. Being halfway through an academic degree is better than being a fresh graduate, because you need to complete the exams. But even so, being a 22-year-old with no full-time job is not good.

It is possible that your visa will be rejected because they think you are trying to immigrate. I cannot say how likely that is.
